# Unable to call Dynamics 365 Events API from an Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to call the Events API from an Azure function using node.js

I have created the web application by following

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/developer/register-web-application-events-api

I got the api endpoint and token.

---

I also registered my Azure function url as the origin when creating the web application.

For example if my function app url is

FnApp Url

https://msazfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/msazfunctionname?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=

In the origin field I registered

https://msazfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/

---

After creating the web application , I followed below link to use Events API in an Azure function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/developer/using-events-api

But when I run the function from azure portal using Code+Test tab , I see the below error in response

Response status : 400

### 2023-06-04T06:40:50Z [Information] Error in Events Api : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Here is the JS code in Node.JS function App

```
const https = require('https');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    try {

        context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function for D365 Events API processed a request.');
       

        try {

        const requestOptions = {

        method : 'GET',

        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

        };


        const fetchUrl = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.svc.dynamics.com/EvtMgmt/api/v2.0/events/published?emApplicationtoken=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx’;

        const response = await fetch(fetchUrl);

        context.log('Response status : '  + response.status);

        const respData = await response.json();

        const JSONrespData = JSON.stringify(respData);

        context.log('Response data as string : ' + respData);

        context.log('Response data as Object : ' , respData);

        context.log('Response data JSON Stringified : ' + JSONrespData);

        } catch(err) {

            context.log('Error in Events Api : ' + err);

        }

       // context.res = data;

        const responseJSON = {

            "data" : respData

        }

        context.res.headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };

        context.res.headers = { "content-type": "application/json" };

        context.res.body = responseJSON; 

        context.done();        

    } catch(err) {

        context.res = {

            status: 500

        };

    }

}
```